# Howto realise server-side plugin concept on a JEE server

Tags: jakarta-ee, plugins, server, osgi

I am writing a JEE 7 Application that runs on a Wildfly 10.1 server. I would like to allow 3rd party developers to program plugins that enhance the core application with several features. The only possibility i know is to use server-side OSGI + Bridge or using microservices ( do not know how to register those services for later lookup by the core application).
Is there some best-practise how to realize serverside-plugins? (maybe without using some spring stuff).
Thanks very much in advance for any idea

Br Shane

Answer (score -1):

I hope that is not too trivial, but: The typical J2EE way is using the JNDI-NamingService, Beans can be registered in JNDI and can be discovered there. So third party developers can implement interfaces, find interfaces,  become registered in JNDI and deploy their applications. Your server-application can provide them with base-functionality and call them, after they have been discovered.

Comment: I would delete the answer, if I understood, why it was voted down. Might anybody enlighten me, why JNDI is not fit to register Plugins.